# Why must I specify a schema in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

The standard way of connecting to a DB with Spring Boot (or at least one of them) is by specifying the database connection properties in this way:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql//database-host/schema
> spring.datasource.username=username
> spring.datasource.password=password

This then enables things like JpaRepository and Entity classes to be configured automatically.  This might be a vague question or not the right forum for it, but I've always wondered why has this not been made more user friendly in its set up for databases with multiple schemas?  What limitations are there in not allowing the entity classes to have schema's set up on a per entity level and thus the JpaRepository implementations read from there.  You can set up multiple schemas if you set up your own data source configurations and there's a variety ways around the problem, but Spring Boot does so much to make a coder's life easy with annotation based configuration.

Is this just not a high priority for a feature?  Is it a non-standard use case? Or is there something in the framework that makes this more challenging?

Comment: You do not have to specify the schema in the URL. This is a JDBC thing; if you don't, the database will pick the schema based on your user, but this is db/driver dependent. You can still, with JPA, define the table name, catalog, and schema within the @Table annotation - it is just that no one does so that they can define schemas on the fly through properties, so that you can have multiple schemas in the same database for testing and not restrict entities to one in particular. If you define a schema on the entity, you'd only be able to override it through orm.xml definitions per entity.